# Sharepoint list in Access not working on certain workstations

Tags: sharepoint, ms-access-2007

Figured I'd throw this out here because in-house because in-house ITS and myself can't figure it out at all.

I have some Access 2007 front-end forms connected to lists in Sharepoint 2010. I updated the columns in a few of the lists in Sharepoint. On some workstations, the lists that were updated cannot be opened in Access anymore. However, they can still be opened directly from the Sharepoint web portal.

Does anyone have any idea what might be going on? Does Access have some sort of hidden cache of the structure of Sharepoint lists? We've tried all the obvious such as deleting and relinking and refreshing the culprit lists. All the computers in question are running the same version of Access and the same version of Windows.

Comment: Do you get any error message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured I would post what happened just for the record.

We are using Sharepoint Server 2010 and Access 2007. The problem was being caused by miscommunication between the two versions. We temporarily fixed it by installing Sharepoint Designer on all the workstations that needed the Sharepoint app, as this updated some of the Office 2007 files to Office 2010 and allowed compatibility with Sharepoint 2010.

Unfortunately, each time Microsoft rolled out an update to Office 2007, it broke the compatibility again, and after one update I was not able to fix it again. I have since moved to a MySQL/PHP platform and never plan on looking at Sharepoint again as a database platform.